# Looping through Columns of Dataframe and dividing values by a value indexed by column name in another dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a data frame like below with lots of columns and data in

```
                 Label 2015-08-24 2015-08-25
   1               AxG   179238.8   174160.3
   2              CHaF   203544.2   199411.9
   3              HHHH   130138.9   129182.2
   4               fLS   146367.0   148708.0
   5               KSU   194584.7   188508.0
   6              MqCC   272922.7   273369.5
   7              BEPU        0.0        0.0
   8              SSEX   107566.4   111552.8
   9               QQQ   248380.4   257064.2
   10              AAA   258735.4   260415.5
```

I have another dataframe that has row index the same as the column names in the first (in this case dates). I want to divide every value in the column of the first dataframe with the corresponding value in the second

```
                      totals
      2015-08-24      1741479
      2015-08-25      199411.9
```

My first idea was to do something like below (I come from  a pythonic background, albeit a while ago)

```
        > for(i in names(df1)){
         + df1[[df1[,i]/df2[i,]]]
```

But this is the error I receive:

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1 In
>   addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(weights[, i],
>   weight_totals[i, ]) :   ‘/’ not meaningful for factors

Any ideas?

Comment: what error? you didn't print it

Comment: `df1[,1] <- df1[,1]/df2[1,1]`
`df1[,2] <- df1[,2]/df2[2,1]`?

Comment: my general approach would be to melt the 1st dataframe and merge/join with the second. You can them normalize and pivot. There will be a problem with column values, however, which cannot be numbers so you will need to munge you data a little bit.

Comment: @maracuja what answer do you expect from the example? Can you post the output that should result?

Comment: is this TRUE `nrow(df2) == ncol(df1)`?

Comment: @PierreLafortune your answers below are correct and your above comment regarding the nrow == ncol is also true. Thank you for the solution as it works perfectly. Jaap's version is also neat given order isn't important and remind me of a pythonic approach. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can also use `sweep`. It is a useful function for any case where a vector of values must be applied over an array. We choose margin `2` to sweep over the columns (we could have chosen `1` for rows):

```
sweep(df[-1], 2, df2$totals, '/')
#      2015-08-24 2015-08-25
# [1,] 0.10292332  0.8733696
# [2,] 0.11688008  1.0000000
# [3,] 0.07472895  0.6478159
# [4,] 0.08404753  0.7457328
# [5,] 0.11173531  0.9453197
# [6,] 0.15671892  1.3708786
# [7,] 0.00000000  0.0000000
# [8,] 0.06176727  0.5594089
# [9,] 0.14262612  1.2891116
# [10,] 0.14857222  1.3059176
```

Answer (score 4):

You could transpose your second `data.frame` and multiply the matching columns using `intersect()`

```
dft <- data.frame(t(df2), check.names = FALSE) # transpose df2

mapply("/", df[intersect(names(df), names(dft))],
        dft[intersect(names(df), names(dft))]) # perfrom division
#      2015-08-24 2015-08-25
# [1,] 0.10292332  0.8733696
# [2,] 0.11688008  1.0000000
# [3,] 0.07472895  0.6478159
# [4,] 0.08404753  0.7457328
# [5,] 0.11173531  0.9453197
# [6,] 0.15671892  1.3708786
# [7,] 0.00000000  0.0000000
# [8,] 0.06176727  0.5594089
# [9,] 0.14262612  1.2891116
#[10,] 0.14857222  1.3059176
```

Data used:

```
df <- structure(list(Label = structure(c(2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 
10L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("AAA", "AxG", "BEPU", "CHaF", "fLS", 
"HHHH", "KSU", "MqCC", "QQQ", "SSEX"), class = "factor"), `2015-08-24` = c(179238.8, 
203544.2, 130138.9, 146367, 194584.7, 272922.7, 0, 107566.4, 
248380.4, 258735.4), `2015-08-25` = c(174160.3, 199411.9, 129182.2, 
148708, 188508, 273369.5, 0, 111552.8, 257064.2, 260415.5)), .Names = c("Label", 
"2015-08-24", "2015-08-25"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

df2 <- structure(list(totals = c(1741479, 199411.9)), .Names = "totals", row.names = c("2015-08-24", 
"2015-08-25"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I thought they were trying to divide

Answer (score 2):

Altough @PierreLafortune has the shortest solution, using `sweep` requires that the order of the column names of `df` and the rownames of `df2` has to be the same. When using `for` (and I suppose also with the `intersect` method of @mtoto) the column names of `df` and the rownames of `df2` don't have to be in the same order to get the desired results. Another advantage is that `df` is updated immediately:

```
for(i in names(df)[-1]) 
  df[, i] <- df[, i] / df2$totals[match(i, row.names(df2))]
```

which gives:

```
> df
   Label 2015-08-24 2015-08-25
1    AxG 0.10292332  0.8733696
2   CHaF 0.11688008  1.0000000
3   HHHH 0.07472895  0.6478159
4    fLS 0.08404753  0.7457328
5    KSU 0.11173531  0.9453197
6   MqCC 0.15671892  1.3708786
7   BEPU 0.00000000  0.0000000
8   SSEX 0.06176727  0.5594089
9    QQQ 0.14262612  1.2891116
10   AAA 0.14857222  1.3059176
```